# Order-Perserving Bijection $f:A\to A^*$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, order-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a well-quasi-ordered infnite set. Does there exist an order-preserving bijection $f:A\to A^*$, where $A^*$ is the free monoid over $A$ under the subword ordering? Would this subword ordering make $A^*$ well-quasi-ordered as well (reference to Corollary $1.7$ of [2]).

References:

1. http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/155notes/lecture19.pdf
2. https://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/bitstream/10023/7963/1/BCCpaperv9.pdf
3. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.5070v2.pdf

---

Crossposted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639834/order-preserving-bijection-fa-to-a).

Comment: Did you mean to write that $A$ is infinite?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes. I know that if $A$ is finite, then this is not possible.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question.

Comment: I suspect that the order you want to use on $A^*$ is not the subword ordering but the following order: $a_1 \cdots a_n \leqslant b_1 \cdots b_m$ if there exists $i_1 < \cdots < i_n$ such that $a_k  \leqslant  b_{i_k}$ for all $k$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Actually, yes.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I assume that you have your own answer now then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood, the answer seems to be no.

Let $A=\omega+1$ with the usual order, or indeed, any well-quasi-ordering with an object having infinitely many predecessors. Such an object would get mapped to an element of $A^*$, which we can think of as a finite term over $A$, and every such term has only finitely many subwords. So the map from $A$ to $A^*$ cannot be both order-preserving and bijective.

Comment: Even if A and A^* are infinite, the same situation results?

Comment: @JulianRachman No, because $\omega$ does biject with $2^{<\omega}$ in an order-preserving way. You can list out all words in countably many letters in an $\omega$ sequence, such that subwords come earlier.

Comment: I do not quite understand. Would you be able to show me from a categorical stand-point?

Comment: And elaborate you on your statement?

Comment: You can make a list of all words in an $\omega$ sequence, such that subwords appear earlier.  Like this:  <>, a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, c, ac, bc, ca, cb, cc, aaa, aab, ..., d, ad, ....  There are various ways to do it. Now just map the nth symbol to the n^th word, and this is an order-preserving bijection.

Comment: Why is it an order-perserving bijection? So how would you restate my statement in my question to make it equivalent to your above statement of this order-perserving bijection?

Comment: By order-preserving, I assumed you meant that if n<m in A, then f(n) is a subword of f(m).  And that is exactly what you get with my enumeration, when I said that subwords appear earlier.

Comment: I think. So what/how can we conclude pertaining to my main question?

Comment: Well, the answer to your question is no, there isn't necessarily such an order-preserving bijection, because I gave a counterexample in my answer. Meanwhile, in the comments, I described how you can have some affirmative instances, such as the case $A=\omega$, where there is such an order-preserving bijection.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand your definition of $\omega$ in comparison to my definition of $A$. Like I don't get with you define $\omega+1$ as well.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  Let me suggest that you simply update your math.stackexchange question to point to our discussion here, and ask your further questions about it over there.  I'm sure that people will be able to explain those matters at the right level.